# Algorithmic approach to find Maximal Product

Tags: java, python, c++, algorithm, data-structures

If 2 integers are given say a and b. Find b positive integers, such that their sum is equal to a and their product is maximal. We have to return the maximum product as an output.

Constraints are -

0<=b<=20

b<=a<=100

What sort of algorithm or approach has to be used to solve this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have two integers x,y such that x < y.

```
(x+1)*(y-1) = x*y + y - x - 1 >= x*y
```

This is saying that we can make the product bigger by increasing x and decreasing y.

Therefore the optimal answer will have all numbers within 1 unit of each other (or else we can get a better answer).

So our numbers are all equal to either x or x+1 (for some x yet to be determined).  Suppose we have k of the bigger numbers, we know there must be b-k of the smaller ones.  We can now compute x and k as follows:

```
x*(b-k)+k*(x+1) = a
b*x - k*x + k*x + k = a
b*x + k = a
```

therefore x = a // b and k = a % b.

The final product will be x**(b-k)*(x+1)**k.

(Note that there appears to be something odd with the question if sum is equal to a and b > a, because this will be impossible to achieve with positive integers.)

Comment: Yes, I have edited the constraints as per you have made your note in the last line so that now there will be no such impossible case.

Comment: S, after changing the edits, the final product x**(b-k)*(x+1)**k will or not ??? @Peter de Rivaz

Comment: Yes, with the edits I would expect this to be correct